# Test whether a specific column/row name is a value in r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to test whether a column is named something specific (and then I would like to do the same with row name). Hence is it possible to loop through each column name to see if it's equal something?

Example:

```
dataframe:
      Jan     Feb     Mar
Jan    0       0       0
Feb    0       0       0
Mar    0       0       0
```

Logic: Loop through each column to find if it's called "Jan" and loop through each row to see if it's called "Feb". If the logic is met then put 1 in equivalent col/row. E.g.

```
Final dataframe:
       Jan     Feb     Mar
Jan    0       0       0
Feb    1       0       0
Mar    0       0       0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `df1["Feb", "Jan"] <- 1`

Comment: I wanted it to loop through if possible

Comment: `rownames()` and `colnames()` will get you vector over which you can loop with e.g. `for` or `purrr::map`

Comment: I have posted an answer which should help you

Answer (score 0):

I have generated your data as follows:

```
df<-data.frame("Jan" = rep(x = 0,times = 3),"Feb" = rep(x = 0,times = 3),"Mar" = rep(x = 0,times = 3))
rownames(df)<-c("Jan","Feb","Mar")
```

This gives the following data frame:

```
    Jan Feb Mar
Jan   0   0   0
Feb   0   0   0
Mar   0   0   0
```

The following explicit function should help you:

```
set_func<-function(dt,col,row){
  nm_col<-colnames(dt)
  nm_row<-rownames(dt)
  if(col %in% nm_col){
    col_id<-which(nm_col == col)
  }
  else {
    cat(col,"is not present as a column name in the input data\n")
  }
  if(row %in% nm_row){
    row_id<-which(nm_row == row)
  }
  else {
    cat(row,"is not present as a row name in the input data\n")
  }
  if(exists("col_id") == T & exists("row_id") == T){
    dt[row_id,col_id]<-1
  }
  return(dt)
}
```

The arguments of the function are:

`dt` - Your input data frame
`col` - The value you are checking for among the column names
`row` - The value you are checking for among the row names

Using this function for your example gives the following result:

```
> set_func(dt = df,col = "Jan",row = "Feb")
    Jan Feb Mar
Jan   0   0   0
Feb   1   0   0
Mar   0   0   0
```

However, if you check for a value which doesn't exist as a column or row name, a message will be printed informing you that the value does not exist.

```
> set_func(dt = df,col = "Apr",row = "Mar")
Apr is not present as a column in the input data
    Jan Feb Mar
Jan   0   0   0
Feb   0   0   0
Mar   0   0   0
```